# Getting null value (Firestore query result) in Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-widget

I have an application and In this i'm making a query for get user details by the e-mail account.
I'm using Future class to get data and fill my variable but the widget Text always show null value.
Please let me now if i am doing something wrong.

```
class _HomePageAppState extends State<HomePageApp> {
String _emailUsuario;
Usuario usuario;

void initState() {
 super.initState();

 Autenticacao().getCurrentUser().then((user) {
 setState(() {
  if (user != null) {
  _emailUsuario = user.email.toString(); //the user email is returnig correctly

  recuperarDadosUsuarioFirebase().then((ds) {
            usuario = Usuario(
              email: _emailUsuario,
              nome: ds['nome'] != null ? ds['nome'] : null,              
            );
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

Future<DocumentSnapshot> recuperarDadosUsuarioFirebase() async {
DocumentSnapshot ds;

await Firestore.instance
  .collection('usuarios')
  .document(_emailUsuario)
   .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot _ds) {
   ds = _ds;
 });

return ds;
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Container(
  color: Colors.white10,
  child: ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Bem vindo ${usuario.nome} !!!'),
   ],
 ),
 ),
 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U might want to use Future Builder for such async work cause build method was called before `usuario` is assign so like this :

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getCurrentUser(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    // after getting data
  },
);
```

Method `getCurrentUser()` needs to be created :)